# Numpy Extract Data from Compressed Sparse Column Format

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, sparse-matrix

I have a mat file with sparse data for around 7000 images with 512x512 dimensions stored in a flattened format (so rows of 262144) and I’m using scipy’s loadmat method to turn this sparse information into a Compressed Sparse Column format. The data inside of these images is a smaller image that’s usually around 25x25 pixels somewhere inside of the 512x512 region , though the actual size of the smaller image is not consitant and changes for each image. I want to get the sparse information from this format and turn it into a numpy array with only the data in the smaller image; so if I have an image that’s 512x512 but there’s a circle in a 20x20 area in the center I want to just get the 20x20 area with the circle and not get the rest of the 512x512 image. I know that I can use .A to turn the image into a non-sparse format and get a 512x512 numpy array, but this option isn’t ideal for my RAM.

Is there a way to extract the smaller images stored in a sparse format without turning the sparse data into dense data?

I tried to turn the sparse data into dense data, reshape it into a 512x512 image, and then I wrote a program to find the top, bottom, left, and right edges of the image by checking for the first occurrence of data from the top, bottom, left, and right but this whole processes seemed horribly inefficient.

Comment: I'm a bit confused about what you actually get with `loadmat`.  Is `data['foobar']` a scipy.sparse.csc` matrix?  What `shape`?  You can index such an matrix, e.g. `M[40:60, 70:90]`, getting another `csc`.  Though converting `toarray()` and slice there might be faster.  In general, sample code (and data) is clearer than word descriptions.

Comment: Please provide a [minimal working example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of your current solution.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry about the little amount of information I provided; I ended up figuring it out.Scipy's loadmat function when used to extract sparse data from a mat file returns a csc_matrix, which I then converted to numpy's compressed sparse column format. Numpy's format has a method `.nonzero()` that will return the index of every non_zero element in that matrix. I then reshaped the numpy csc matrix into 512x512, and then used `.nonzero()` to get the non-zero elements in 2D, then used used those indexes to figure out the max height and width of my image I was interested in. Then I created a numpy matrix of zeros the size of the image I wanted, and set the elements in that numpy matrix to the elements to the pixels I wanted by indexing into my numpy csc matrix (after I called `.tocsr()` on it)